# fear on that head

Tags: meaning

-It certainly did not become him to fear Lady Laura on the score of rank, if it was to be allowed to Mr. Kennedy to proceed without **fear on that head**. (Anthony Trollope )

-He could not believe his father had any such intention; and that if he discovered anything of that kind, it was only when he was in a frenzy, and a melancholy disorder had seized him; and that David had nothing to **fear on that head**. (Bible)

-I assured him he had nothing to fear **on that head** (Blackwood's Edinburgh Magazine)

Even Oxford and Random House have not ON THAT HEAD; what does it mean?

Thank you. Joe.

Comment: I've never seen that usage before and it makes no sense to me.  I would have thought it an isolated mis-use were it not for the fact that you found three instances of it!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're mistakenly grouping the word "fear" with the idiom "on that head", which is unrelated. The latter is a somewhat uncommon (although not unheard of) way of expressing "on that front", or "in that regard".

Your third example, for instance, is equivalent to:

> I assured him he had nothing to fear in that regard.

Here are some examples of its usage decoupled from the word "fear":

- "... all sums due to and from the trustees of naval and military pensions previously to the period at which any payment from the Bank of England on that head ceased to be due ..." - [(Mirror of Parliament)](http://books.google.ca/books?id=oppHAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA753&lpg=PA753&dq=%22on+that+head%22&source=bl&ots=7L87Ys-8hV&sig=8dfdPffm3mJHm5BP26-8ELgmHEY&hl=en&sa=X&ei=6K3sUZjwN5be4APPGQ&ved=0CCkQ6AEwADgK#v=onepage&q=%22on%20that%20head%22&f=false)
- "He has not said enough on that head ; I know a great deal more of it ..." - [(Mr Bayle's Historical and Critical Dictionary)](http://books.google.ca/books?id=wmtXAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA798&lpg=PA798&dq=%22on+that+head%22&source=bl&ots=pu5rc39LWn&sig=rzOmmuiHqfFlQxHRQVwV5pXxAhc&hl=en&sa=X&ei=6K3sUZjwN5be4APPGQ&ved=0CCsQ6AEwATgK#v=onepage&q=%22on%20that%20head%22&f=false)